# bootstrap 3 thumbnail not repeating across the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I know I have done something silly, but still learning BS3, can anybody tell me why this page does not go across in three rows, but shows only one per row?

I am using data driven information, code is below, and my problem can be viewed at http://ncpeachrecipes.com/index.php (I know this is usually frowned upon, hope this is ok)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="DETAILS.data">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img class="img-circle" src="" data-binding-src="images/th_{{IMAGE}}" />
<div class="caption" align="center">
<h5><strong>{{NAME}}</strong></h5>
<p><a href="show_recipe.php?ID={{ID}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View the Recipe</a> </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>          
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you create a row and 1 column this means it will only create 1 colum.

If you put the repeat in the column block it will create them alongside each other instead of underneath.